# Amazon S3 get bucket location returns ListAllMyBucketsResult instead

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to use the S3 API to get the location (region) of a bucket. I'm following the docs (http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html)

and I've constructed the following request:

```
GET http://s3.amazonaws.com/?location
Host: bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 18:21:59 GMT
Authorization: AWS <my auth string>
```

But rather than getting a "LocationConstraint" XML response, I get the "ListAllMyBucketsResult" (which just lists all the buckets in my account).

What am I doing wrong? BTW, the bucket I'm testing against is located in the EU.

Comment: what is the <my auth string>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, I found the solution:

The bucket name must also be included in the URL, like this:

```
GET http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/?location
Host: bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com
Date: Thu, 03 Mar 2011 18:21:59 GMT
Authorization: AWS <my auth string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an error in your call. I would start with either [s3cmd.rb](http://www.s3sync.net/wiki) or [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) just to be sure that you get the information from publicly vetted tools. Try:

```
s3cmd info s3://my-bucket-name
```

or
    s3cmd.rb  location my-bucket-name

should give you the location info. Obviously you'll need to configure the s3 auth stuff.